# Stream Aurora MySQL data changes into Kinesis Streams

Tags: mysql, amazon-kinesis, amazon-aurora

I am trying to **stream Aurora MySQL data changes to Kinesis streams**. What could be the best possible way to do this considering the fact that **each and every record should be streamed into kinesis**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are possibly numerous ways to do this, one of the popular one would be as follows:

1. Enable binlogs in your cluster [1]
2. Have a client (possibly a lambda function or an ec2 instance) that reads your binlog stream
3. Create your Kinesis stream
4. Make the client from Step 2 publish to your Kinesis stream from #3.

You can read articles [2] and [3] for reference. What you need is split between the two docs. ([3] is for postgres, but has some explanation about using lambdas or ec2 clients).

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/enable-binary-logging-aurora/

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/streaming-changes-in-a-database-with-amazon-kinesis/

[3] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have one question. How lambda function will get invoke ? As per my understanding lambda requires event source to get invoked.

Comment: Depends on how you write your lambda function. You can make your lambda constantly poll for the binlogs in a single invoke, there by keeping your lambda warm always (thereby making it expensive), or write your lambda such that a single invoke polls for a fixed amount of data or a fixed duration of data. If written that way, you can then hook a Cloudwatch Event that can go and trigger your lambda every now and then. This is a not a cut and dried solution, I'm just thinking out loud here.

Comment: I came across this blog -https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/capturing-data-changes-in-amazon-aurora-using-aws-lambda/ Here it says that using procedure i can call lambda function asynchronously and in that lambda function i can write code to push data into kinesis. But how can i be sure that lambda is successful in inserting all the records into kinesis.

Comment: You would need to emit metrics for records read and validate it with a describe call in kinesis most likely.

Comment: @RohitMane Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post/answer?

Comment: Well I am not sure how I can use metrics to make sure that I am not missing any record. I was thinking of storing status of each record in the table. But what if my write operation failed.

Comment: Storing status in table is also doable, but perhaps a cheaper alternative would be to track the number of entries in your stream at the start of the lambda invocation, and track the number of comitted writes to kinesis, and asserting that those match at the end of the invocation. If lambda didn't succeed for your batch, track that. You could write that to a DB (like you mentioned) but typically you'd push something like that to Cloudwatch Logs.

Comment: I will be calling lambda function from stored procedure in asynchronous way for each record. Because Aurora MySQL supports lambda invocation from procedure in asynchronous way only. That's why I was thinking of maintaining status of each record in separate table.